# Is $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{\omega} \times \mathbb R^{\omega}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

As a study exercise, I'm trying to find a topological space $X$ which is homeomorphic to $X \times X$. I began thinking of simple examples involving $\mathbb R$ but then realized my best bet would be infinite dimensional, otherwise most of the time I couldn't have even a bijection. I'm almost sure that I've constructed a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R^{\omega} = \prod_{i\in\mathbb N} \mathbb R$ and the cartesian product with itself: $$ f:\mathbb R^{\omega} \times \mathbb R^{\omega}\to\mathbb R^{\omega} \atop{\left((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right)\mapsto (c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}, c_n=\left\{\begin{align} &a_n, \quad n\text{ even} \\ &b_n, \quad n\text{ odd} \end{align}\right.}$$
Here we can see $f^{-1}((c_n))=((c_{2k}),(c_{2k+1}))$. Here the topologies involved are the usual ones, that is, the product topology in $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ (taking in $\mathbb R$ the standard metric topology), and the product topology again for the cartesian product with itself. I've tested for continuity and I'm pretty sure it's all good, but could someone tell me if I'm correct here? Thanks.

This happens to be the function I was able to construct, but my original intuition is that one sequence and two sequences next to each other are basically the same thing. Also if anyone happens to know a simpler example of the problem in my first sentence, please share.

P.S. I should be using simple topological arguments here; open and closed sets, antiimages, the likes.

Comment: A quick correction: There is always a bijection between $X$ and $X\times X$. Continuity is the tough part.

Comment: a silly answer: if $X$ is just a point then $X \times X$ is homeomorphic to $X$

Comment: @StellaBiderman Indeed? Where can I find this result?

Comment: Are you familiar with the proof that $|\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Q}|$?

Comment: Yes I am, but intermediate steps only involved the existence of bijections $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N\times\dots\times\mathbb N$, not for any $X$ (the way it was presented to me).

Comment: I'm aware that a bijection exists if there's injections both ways, but I can't think of such injections...

Comment: @StellaBiderman Wait though, that certainly can't be true for finite sets??

Comment: Ah, true. I should have said that having infinite carnality is equivalent to the existence of such a bijection.

Comment: The arguement for $X$ and $X\times X$ is the same. Consider $\{a_x\}$, the elements of $X$ indexed by themselves, and use this in place of the countable labeling of $\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, your formula

$$\left((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right)\mapsto (c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}, c_n=\left\{\begin{align} &a_n, \quad n\text{ even} \\ &b_n, \quad n\text{ odd} \end{align}\right.$$

isn't quite correct, as is, you're dropping terms. You mean

$$\left((a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\right)\mapsto (c_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}, c_n=\left\{\begin{align} &a_{n/2}, \quad n\text{ even} \\ &b_{(n-1)/2}, \quad n\text{ odd} \end{align}\right.$$

judging by your formula for $f^{-1}$.

Yes, $f$ is a homeomorphism. To see that, use that a function into a topological product is continuous if and only if the function composed with any projection from the product to one of the factors is continuous.

You have

$$\pi_{2k}\circ f = \pi_k \circ \pi_a;\qquad \pi_{2k+1}\circ f = \pi_k \circ \pi_b,$$

and the projections $\pi_k$, $\pi_a$, and $\pi_b$ are continuous, hence $f$ is continuous. Conversely, you have

$$\pi_k \circ \pi_a \circ f^{-1} = \pi_{2k};\qquad \pi_k \circ \pi_b \circ f^{-1} = \pi_{2k+1},$$

which shows that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous.

Comment: Oh wow that's a slip up yes.

Comment: Also thank you that is a very concise argument, I had thought of using subbases which complicated things a bit.

Comment: What I really wanted was to just "put $a_n$ and $b_n$ next to each other" rather than "interlace them" but I couldn't think of how seeing as none of them has an end at which the other could start.

Comment: Yes, you can't put them "next to each other" in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. You could put them next to each other in $\mathbb{R}^{\omega+\omega}$ (ordinal sum in the exponent), which is canonically homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\omega\times \mathbb{R}^\omega$. But showing $\mathbb{R}^{\omega+\omega} \cong \mathbb{R}^\omega$ requires some interlacing.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to argue using the discrete topology.  Similarly, you could use $\Bbb Z_2^\omega$ with the same argument as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9795/are-they-isomorphic/9796#9796)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm practicing the product topology which is why i chose it, but yes I can see how it'd be easier

Comment: Yes, this is the Cantor set (so $C = C \times C$ for the Cantorset $C$). Also $\mathbb{N}^\omega$ works and is homeomorphic to the irrationals (so $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \simeq \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$).